# Running GNU Parallel via ssh login on a linux and a mac machine

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I can run Parallel on my machine fine. I looked up running Parallel on a remote machine, I found this syntax:

```
parallel –S 16/node1,16/node2,16/node3,16/node4 –-workdir . ./ B1_rosettaCM_singletarget.sh {}
::: {1..48}
```

However, they state it's for passwordless log in, which I don't have set up. i wonder how I can change this syntax to run the bash script on my remote machine (for which I have the Linux login/password). What is the workdir?

Will this work on a mac as well? Do I need to install the software I'm running in identical path on the Linux machine, or does Parallel take care of that? How about the mac?

Comment: What's the objection to setting up password-less login? Just do it. If you need to run a specific program on the remote machines it will need to be installed on them. No, you don't necessarily need to install **GNU Parallel** on the remote machines, but why not install it anyway? Macs can run **GNU Parallel** easily, yes - use **homebrew** to install it with `brew install parallel`. `workdir` is the working directory where **GNU Parallel** will run.

Answer (score 0):

> I can run Parallel on my machine fine. I looked up running Parallel on
>   a remote machine, I found this syntax:
>
> ```
> parallel –S 16/node1,16/node2,16/node3,16/node4 –-workdir . ./ B1_rosettaCM_singletarget.sh {}
> ::: {1..48}
> ```

This syntax is wrong - probably due to a wordprocessor "fixing" the formatting. It should be:

```
 parallel –S 16/node1,16/node2,16/node3,16/node4 --workdir . ./B1_rosettaCM_singletarget.sh {} ::: {1..48}
```

> However, they state it's for passwordless log in, which I don't have set up.

You can set that up in several ways:

- ssh-agent. This is the best way to do this. See how https://www.cs.utah.edu/~bigler/code/sshkeys.html (step 1 and 2) and https://oletange.wordpress.com/2016/05/22/ssh-agent-in-new-terminal-window/
- ssh-keys with no passphrase. See: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html
- sshpass. `SSHPASS=$(ssh-askpass) parallel --ssh 'sshpass ssh'`

> What is the workdir?

From `man parallel`:

```
       The special mydir value . uses the current
       working dir.  If the current working dir is
       beneath your home dir, the value . is treated
       as the relative path to your home dir. This
       means that if your home dir is different on
       remote computers (e.g. if your login is
       different) the relative path will still be
       relative to your home dir.
```

> Will this work on a mac as well?

Yes.

> Do I need to install the software I'm
>   running in identical path on the Linux machine, or does Parallel take
>   care of that?

If GNU Parallel is installed on the remote system, it will automatically figure out the number of cores (so the `16/` will not be needed). It does not need to be in the identical path, but just somewhere in your path. GNU Parallel does not take care of that.

> How about the mac?

The same applies to the mac.

GNU Parallel is not tested intensively on macs, so if you find something that works on GNU/Linux, but which does not work on a mac, you should feel free to file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try all that, for now I do want to ask a question because I feel I wasn't clear enough. Inside B1_rosettaCM_singletarget.sh I'm running a program installed on my machine from path say /home/user/program/module, do I need to install that same program in the same exact path on the other machine?

Comment: You should ask the author of `B1_rosettaCM_singletarget.sh` that question.